# Rename and Move file if destination path already exists?

Tags: python, file-rename

I am trying to create a script that moves all pictures from my downloads folder, to my pictures folder. My script works this far (moving the files over), except when it tries to move a file that already has the same name in the destination folder - like with printscreens. It will not move the file if printscreen1.png already exists in pictures.

For files like this, I would like to rename the file and add the date or time to the file name, then move it without replacing the original printscreen so I can keep both and all printscreens going toward the future.

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

downloadsb = os.path.join('B:\\Downloads')
pictures = os.path.join('B:\\Pictures')

for f in os.listdir(downloadsb):
    if f.endswith((".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".png", ".ico", ".psd", ".sfw", ".webp", ".pdd", ".psb", ".bmp", ".rle", ".dib", ".eps", ".iff", ".tdi", ".jpf",
    ".jpx", ".jp2", ".j2c", ".jxk", ".jpc", ".jps", ".mp0", ".pcx", ".pdp", ".raw", ".pxr", ".pns")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(downloadsb, f), pictures)
        
    if os.path.isfile(f):
                os.rename(f,f + "date")
```

Here is my error message:

```
raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst
shutil.Error: Destination path 'B:\Pictures\printscreen1.png' already exists
```

This is what I have so far, I would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you

Comment: You're renaming the file after you try to move it right now; that should probably happen before.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in library that checks to see if a file is an image.  Also, you need to iterate over the files in the directory (folder).  Something like this should work (not tested):

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import imghdr

downloadsb = os.path.join('B:\\Downloads')
pictures = os.path.join('B:\\Pictures')

files = os.listdir(downloadsb)

for f in files:
    try:
        imghdr.what(f)
        dest_name = f
        if os.path.exists( os.path.join(pictures, dest_name) ):
            dest_name += datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
        shutil.move(os.path.join(downloadsb, f),
                    os.path.join(pictures, dest_name))

    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not check it before moving. Something like below

NOTE: When the file exists you can do different types of renaming. I and just appending _new (to the extension). Not quite what you wanted but that should give an idea

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime
import glob

downloadsb = os.path.join('src')
pictures = os.path.join('dst')

for f in glob.glob(downloadsb + '/*'):
    if f.endswith(
        (".jpg", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".png", ".ico", ".psd", ".sfw", ".webp", ".pdd", ".psb", ".bmp",
         ".rle", ".dib", ".eps", ".iff", ".tdi", ".jpf", ".jpx", ".jp2", ".j2c", ".jxk", ".jpc", ".jps",
         ".mp0", ".pcx", ".pdp", ".raw", ".pxr", ".pns")):

        dstFile = os.path.join(pictures, os.path.split(f)[1])
        if os.path.exists(dstFile):
            # Do whatever you want to rename the file here
            shutil.move(f, dstFile + '_new')
        else:
            shutil.move(f, dstFile)
```

Before running

```
dst:
tmp.jpg

src:
tmp.jpg
```

After running

```
dst:
tmp.jpg  tmp.jpg_new

src:
```